# Setting up PPTP VPN server, cannot access remote hosts

Tags: vpn, pptp

I'm attempting to set up a VPN server on an industrial ProRoute M2M 4G router. My goal is for a client to be able to log in on the VPN and be able to "locally" hosts that are on the router's LAN. My first challenge comes from the obscure PPTP server settings on the router configuration pages. I have tried every possible combination I can think of. However, the one's included below are what were used to generate the following outputs.

My local machine is 192.168.1.64 and my local gateway 192.168.1.254. The remote router has gateway 192.168.8.1 and DHCP assigns LAN addresses 192.168.8.100-192.168.8.200. I am running Windows 7, but have also experimented with this using OS X. The router is using a fixed public IP sim card.

**Router Settings**

Local IP - 192.168.8.100-192.168.8.200

Remote IP - 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200

Encryption - MPPE 128 bit (tested everything without encryption too)

Username and Password - Set

User Static IP - Left blank

Remote LAN/Mask - 192.168.8.0/24

Please note that I have no option of enabling DHCP for the PPTP server anywhere.

**Local Client Settings**

IPv6 - Disabled

IPv4 - All automatic, although tested with static with identical results, DNS manually pointed to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 (Google Public DNS) and default gateway box is checked

ipconfig output without VPN connection:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a985:527b:f5e3:a66b%11  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.64  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254  

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway.2wire.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:34ff:3fd9:3f57:febf  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34ff:3fd9:3f57:febf%13  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

route print without VPN connection:

```
===========================================================================  
Interface List  
 11...44 8a 5b 61 bd d3 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1  
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter  
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
===========================================================================  

IPv4 Route Table  
===========================================================================  
Active Routes:  
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric  
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.64     10  
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.64    266  
     192.168.1.64  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64    266  
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64    266  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.64    259  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64    266  
===========================================================================  
Persistent Routes:  
  None  

IPv6 Route Table  
===========================================================================  
Active Routes:  
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway  
 13     58 ::/0                     On-link  
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link  
 13     58 2001::/32                On-link  
 13    306 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:34ff:3fd9:3f57:febf/128  
                                    On-link  
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link  
 13    306 fe80::/64                On-link  
 13    306 fe80::34ff:3fd9:3f57:febf/128  
                                    On-link  
 11    266 fe80::a985:527b:f5e3:a66b/128  
                                    On-link  
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 13    306 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link  
===========================================================================  
Persistent Routes:  
  None
```

ipconfig with VPN connection:

```
Windows IP Configuration


PPP adapter VPN Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a985:527b:f5e3:a66b%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.64
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway.2wire.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:102f:dd7:3f57:fe9b
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::102f:dd7:3f57:fe9b%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C4127ACE-546B-4448-B79A-D0807C092C0B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

route print with VPN connection:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 20...........................VPN Connection
 11...44 8a 5b 61 bd d3 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.64   4235
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.100     11
     93.91.45.109  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.64   4236
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.64   4491
     192.168.1.64  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64   4491
    192.168.1.100  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.100    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64   4491
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.64   4485
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.100     11
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.64   4491
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.100    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 13     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13     58 2001::/32                On-link
 13    306 2001:0:9d38:6abd:102f:dd7:3f57:fe9b/128
                                    On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    306 fe80::102f:dd7:3f57:fe9b/128
                                    On-link
 11    266 fe80::a985:527b:f5e3:a66b/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

tracert 192.168.8.1 (remote router gateway) with VPN connection:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.8.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I can get a VPN connection successfully. I can access the internet through the router if using IP addresses (DNS doesn't seem to work). However, I cannot access any internal hosts on the remote router LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The issue was incorrect remote/local IP ranges. Make sure that remote IP and remote subnet are the IP ranges of your client's network and local is that of the router network.